# Ubuntu + Nodejs + curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, curl, httpresponse

I have a nodejs process listening a port on my server:

```
app.get('/statistic', function(req, res) {
        log_get_connection(req);

        getStatistic().then(statistic => {
                res.json(statistic);
        });

});
```

When I try to access it via curl being on the same machine:

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:<PORT>/statistic"
# or
curl "http://<EXT_IP>:<PORT>/statistic"
```

I get:

```
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host EXT_IP left intact

curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

But when I access it via curl from another server I see a successful HTTP response.

I don't override `res`. Also if I put `console.log(statistic)` before `res.json(statistic)`, I see that `statistic` is correct.

What's even more interesting - this setup worked perfectly fine for some time...

**UPD**: ufw is disabled.

Comment: have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: Do you can run curl with `-v` parameter  (for verbose). And what happens when you try on the root route?

Comment: @user158 no, it's very undesirable

Comment: @zzomrot why is that? aren't you in a testing environment? I said so because you have said that things worked fine previously.

Comment: What version of node are you running? What happens when you try using `res.json()` outside of the promise scope? If node is using the same or later version of V8 that Chrome 32 uses then promises are likely natively supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i find error - in the nodejs code there is a part which parses a file. The file has expanded and the execution of the method takes a long time.

Apparently, it so coincided that when I made a request from a third-party server, the method managed to work out and return data, and when asked from the server itself did not have time.

I found an error when the server stopped returning the result to a third-party server and `console.log(statistic)` before `res.json(statistic)` stopped working.

Thank you for your replies!